# Better way of conditionally adding several new columns, filled with entries that depend on entries of other columns

Tags: r

I have the following data frame:

```
    CustomerID  Department  Price  SportswearDemand  HomeDemand  KidswearDemand  WomenswearDemand
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    1050091     Sportswear  497.6  0                 0           0               0                          
    1555018     Womenswear  336.0  0                 0           0               0                       
    210239      Womenswear  698.0  0                 0           0               0                       
    507556      Sportswear  209.0  0                 0           0               0                        
    1708193     Sportswear  209.0  0                 0           0               0                        
    1295733     Menswear    209.0  0                 0           0               0                        
    1213373     Sportswear  298.0  0                 0           0               0                       
    753471      Sportswear  209.0  0                 0           0               0                        
    82739       Menswear    349.0  0                 0           0               0                        
    1660995     Kidswear    424.6  0                 0           0               0
      .
      .
      .
```

All the columns including and to the right of `SportswearDemand` I'll from now on be referring to as the "demand columns". I want to populate these based on information from `Department` and `Price` as follows:

If, for a certain `customerID`, the Department contains the entry `Sportswear`, then I want the price of that row to be fed into the `SportswearDemand` instead of the current zero. Same thing for the other demand columns. The final result should look like this:

```
   CustomerID  Department  Price  SportswearDemand  HomeDemand  KidswearDemand  WomenswearDemand
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   1050091    Sportswear   497.6  497.6             0           0               0
   1555018    Womenswear   336.0  0                 0           0               336.0
   210239     Womenswear   698.0  0                 0           0               698.0
   507556     Sportswear   209.0  209.0             0           0               0
   1708193    Sportswear   209.0  209.0             0           0               0
   1295733    Menswear     209.0  0                 0           0               0
   1213373    Sportswear   298.0  298.0             0           0               0
   753471     Sportswear   209.0  209.0             0           0               0
   82739      Menswear     349.0  0                 0           0               0
   1660995    Kidswear     424.6  0                 0           424.6           0
     .
     .
     .
```

I've managed to solve it like this:

```
df$SportswearDemand <- with(df, ifelse(df$Department == "Sportswear", df$Price, 0))
df$HomeDemand <- with(df, ifelse(df$Department == "Home", df$Price, 0))
df$KidswearDemand <- with(df, ifelse(df$Department == "Kidswear", df$Price, 0))
df$WomenswearDemand <- with(df, ifelse(df$Department == "Womenswear", df$Price, 0))
```

However, I have 30 more of these demand columns and I'm wondering if there is a better way of doing this than hard coding 30 lines like this?

My first idea was to encapsulate a row in a for loop like this:

```
DemandColumns # array of all the 30 different demand columns stored as strings

for (i in DemandColumns){
 df$i <- with(df, ifelse(df$Department == substr(i,1,nchar(i)-6), df$Price, 0))
}
```

But it just adds a column `"i"` filled with zeros.
The `substr` is used to fetch all the characters except the string `"Demand"`. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to initialise the "demand columns", delete them first.

```
df[grep('Demand', names(df))] <- NULL
```

Create a copy of `Price` and `Department` columns and get data in wide format.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(value = Price, 
         name = Department) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value, 
              names_glue = '{name}_Demand', values_fill = 0)

#   CustomerID Department Price Sportswear_Demand Womenswear_Demand Menswear_Demand Kidswear_Demand
#        <int> <chr>      <dbl>             <dbl>             <dbl>           <dbl>           <dbl>
# 1    1050091 Sportswear  498.              498.                 0               0              0 
# 2    1555018 Womenswear  336                 0                336               0              0 
# 3     210239 Womenswear  698                 0                698               0              0 
# 4     507556 Sportswear  209               209                  0               0              0 
# 5    1708193 Sportswear  209               209                  0               0              0 
# 6    1295733 Menswear    209                 0                  0             209              0 
# 7    1213373 Sportswear  298               298                  0               0              0 
# 8     753471 Sportswear  209               209                  0               0              0 
# 9      82739 Menswear    349                 0                  0             349              0 
#10    1660995 Kidswear    425.                0                  0               0            425.
```

Comment: When I do it, I'm getting the this error: Can't convert <double> to <list>. Why does it convert my doubles to lists?

Comment: Hmm..that's weird. Is it possible to provide a reproducible example using `dput` which can reproduce this error ? I would also try to add `values_fn = mean` in `pivot_wider` to see if it fixes the error.

Comment: Ok that solved it. However I don't like when I don't understand stuff. Do you know why I needed to do it but not you? I have one more thing. Lets say I have another 10 columns, call them quantity columns  (Sportswear_Qty etc) which instead of the Demand suffix have Qty suffix. In these columns I need to add 1 if DepartmentQty = Department in the Department row and 0 if not. Should I just duplicate above code again but with value = 1 and values_fill = 0? Or can I somehow extend the above code to do this as well?

Comment: I think that is because in your actual data there are duplicate rows for a `CustomerID`. The data that you have shown has no duplicates. For your 2nd question, I don't have the necessary data to test but I think it needs to be handled differently. Using `value = 1` and `values_fill = 0` might not work. You might give it a try though.